# 'operator =' function is unavailable because of a const member

Tags: c++

What is the best way to handle this problem? I would like 'x' to remain const.

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo(int x) : x(x) { }
    const int x;
};

void main()
{
    Foo a(0), b(1);
    b = a; // error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Foo'
}
```

Comment: *"I would like 'x' to remain const"*  Why?  You're trying to change it.

Comment: Because it will never change, an std algoritm that Im using requires the 'operator='. I know I can get rid of const and it would work but also woud be interesting to know if there is another way.

Comment: Either have it remain `const` and disable `operator=`, or change it so it is not `const` (or I suppose have `operator=` leave `x` as is. This is going to make your users want to kill you, however).

Comment: How are you benefiting from making it `const`?  Is it to prevent code outside of `Foo` from changing it?

Comment: The object life cycle is: created, bunch of read only operations, destroyd. x will never change. The 'operator=' is used by an std::vector not by me.

Answer (score 2):

Make `x` private. Add a public  function such as `int getX()` to return the value. For ex.:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x) : _x(x) {}
    int getX(){return _x;}
private:
    int _x;
};
```

Now only way to change x is to call constructor which is the behavior you want (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler won't generate the default version of `operator=` (which assigns each data member) because it has no way of knowing what you want to do with that const data member. That doesn't mean you can't write your own `operator=`, it only means that the compiler won't provide one for you. So decide what you want to do with that const data member and write an assignment operator that does it, along with anything else the assignment operator needs to do.